# Unexpected high impedance

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

I am trying to make a block for an 8-bit multiplier, and the testbench is giving me a result that basically says that I don't know what I'm doing with my wires and regs. To make this easier to answer, I'm going to display my code, and then the parts that I think are important:

```
module multiplier_result(
    input ADD_cmd,
    input LOAD_cmd,
    input SHIFT_cmd,
    input reset,
    input [7:0] B_in,
     input [7:0] Add_out,
     input cout,
    output wire [7:0] RB,
    output wire [15:0] RC,
     output wire [8:0] temp_reg, 
    output wire LSB
    );

wire [8:0] from_mux;
reg[16:0] balreg; 
reg tempadd;
        
//assign the outputs. all combinational
assign RB = balreg[15:8];
assign RC = balreg[15:0];
assign LSB = balreg[0];
assign temp_reg = balreg[16:8];

mux_9 mux(
            .sel(~ADD_cmd),
            .Add_out(Add_out), 
            .cout(cout),
            .mux_out(from_mux),
            .temp_reg(temp_reg)
            );

always @ (*) begin
    if(reset) begin
        balreg[16:0] = 17'd0;
        tempadd = 1'b0;
    end
    
    else
    begin
        if(LOAD_cmd) 
        begin
            balreg[16:8] = 9'b000000000;
            balreg[7:0] = B_in;
        end 
        
        if(SHIFT_cmd)
        begin
            balreg[16:8] = from_mux;
            balreg = balreg >> 1;
        end
             
    end
end

endmodule
```

Here is what's troubling me:

[image]

I'm assigning wires to different bits of the `balreg` register (in black). What is going on in my head:

[image]

But for some reason, `LSB` gets what it's supposed to, while `RB` and `RC` get high impedance. Here is the simulation result, followed by the code I used (just a simple test case):

[image]

```
module multiplier_result_tb(
    );

reg ADD_cmd;
reg LOAD_cmd;
reg SHIFT_cmd;
reg reset;
reg [7:0] B_in;
reg [8:0] Add_out;
wire [7:0] RB;
wire [15:0] RC;
wire [8:0] temp_reg; //size 9
wire LSB;
 
multiplier_result dut(ADD_cmd,LOAD_cmd,SHIFT_cmd,reset,B_in,Add_out,RB,RC,temp_reg,LSB);

initial begin
LOAD_cmd = 0;
#10;
LOAD_cmd = 1;
reset = 0;
B_in = 8'b00001010;
Add_out = 9'd0;
ADD_cmd = 0;
SHIFT_cmd = 0;
end
endmodule
```

I'm not following these results at all. The `balreg` register is all set up, so the `RB` and `RC` wires *must* be defined. But according to the simulation, they are high impedance.

The only conclusion is that I really don't know what's going on with the types (the model I had in my head worked for me so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only connected 10 of the 11 ports of the `dut`.  Many tools issue warning messages; check your log file.  You are making connections by position, not by name.  You connected `RB` to `input cout`.  You need to drive `cout` in your testbench.

Another way to make connections is by name.  This is more verbose, but it can make your code clearer:

```
multiplier_result dut (
        // Inputs:
    .ADD_cmd    (ADD_cmd),
    .Add_out    (Add_out),
    .B_in       (B_in),
    .LOAD_cmd   (LOAD_cmd),
    .SHIFT_cmd  (SHIFT_cmd),
    .cout       (cout),
    .reset      (reset),
        // Outputs:
    .LSB        (LSB),
    .RB         (RB),
    .RC         (RC),
    .temp_reg   (temp_reg)
);
```